# How can I stop org mode from moving my figures to the last page?

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode, figure

I'm currently trying to write up my thesis in emacs org-mode, and have run into some problems with file inclusions.

When I include figures with:

```
#+NAME: fig:banana
#+CAPTION: this is a figure caption
[[/path/to/image.png]]
```

(or using a pdf) it works fine. But when I insert another image, it is somehow moved to the end of the file instead of being inserted where it is called.

My pdf-export process (in my `~/.emacs` file) looks like this:

```
(setq org-latex-pdf-process
  '("latexmk -pdflatex='pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode' -pdf -bibtex -f %f"))
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A friend of mine pointed me to the LaTex package `placeins`.

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{placeins}

* section 1
** hi!

#+TITLE: fig:banana
#+CAPTION: this is a banana figure
[[/link/to/banana.png]]

\FloatBarrier

* section 2
```

The `FloatBarrier` stops floats (figures are floats) from jumping over them. I will need to look into passing [tbh] options to figures from org mode further.

Answer (score 2):

Check the `org-mode` manual on how to pass placement options such as `[h]`, `[t]` etc. to the`LaTeX` compiler.

If you're not sure how to control where figures (more precisely, floats) get placed by `LaTeX`, please refer to any introduction.

Or do you want the figure to be placed where you include it?  If so, you might not need it to be a float.

Comment: _Or do you want the figure to be placed where you include it? If so, you might not need it to be a float._ The key point to remember is, that the `#+CAPTION:` line triggers export as a float.